# Celery shared tasks hang until a normal task is run

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm working with Celery and Django. I have two tasks:

```py
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_normal_task(self):
    print('Hello World')

@shared_task(bind=True)
def debug_shared_task(self):
    print('Hello World')
```

Whenever I try to run `debug_shared_task`, Celery hangs indefinitely, every time. It does this until I run `debug_normal_task` once.
As soon as I run `debug_normal_task`, `debug_shared_task` starts working perfectly, every time.

The same goes with every single one of my shared tasks project-wide.
None of them work -> I run a single normal task anywhere -> all of them work.

I could switch all of them to normal tasks, or just run a normal task when the project starts, but I'd like to understand why it's behaving this way to begin with.

---

Here are the files involved:

##### views.py

```py
from ceom.celery import debug_normal_task, debug_shared_task

def news(request):
    debug_shared_task.delay() #Doesn't work
    debug_normal_task.delay()
    debug_shared_task.delay() #Works
    ...
```

##### celery.py

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os

from celery import Celery, shared_task
from celery.schedules import crontab
from ceom.celeryq.tasks_periodic import update_datasets

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ceom.settings")

app = Celery("ceom")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_normal_task(self):
    print('Hello World')

@shared_task(bind=True)
def debug_shared_task(self):
    print('Hello World')
```

##### __init__.py

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from ceom.celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

I'll admit I don't really know exactly what __init__.py does here. I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591449/celery-task-hangs-after-calling-delay-in-django). It's my understanding that I have to import something from celery.py, otherwise it won't be run and the tasks won't be registered. I think something similar might be happening for my shared task issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hey, have you solved the issue? I have noticed same thing. If I import anything from celery.py, seems that tasks decorated as shared_task work otherwise I get a DisabledBackend Error